# Inheritance of combinated templated types

Tags: c++11, inheritance, types

I would like to make a class that inherits of a combination of two templated types like this for example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <set>

template<typename T, typename Base=std::vector<T>>
class A : public Base
{
};

int main()
{
    A<int> a;
    A<int, std::set<int>> b;

    return 0;
}
```

But now, I would like to be able to write

```
    A<int, std::set> b;
```

instead of

```
    A<int, std::set<int>> b;
```

How can I do this please?
Thanks! :)

## SOLUTION from @Piotr S.

Here I repost the complete solution given by Piotr S. so this very nice answer is easier to find for others (don't forget to vote for his answer :-P):

```
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template <template <typename...> class> struct tag {}; 

template <typename T, template <typename...> class Base = std::vector>
class A : public Base<T>
{
public:
    void add(const T& t)
    {
        return _add(tag<Base>{}, t);
    }

private:
    void _add(tag<std::set>, const T& t)
    {
        std::cout << "set\n";
        Base<T>::insert(t);
    }

    void _add(tag<std::vector>, const T& t)
    {
        std::cout << "vector\n";
        Base<T>::push_back(t);
    }
};

int main()
{
    A<int> a;
    A<int, std::set> b;

    a.add(1);
    b.add(1);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I got stuck with this error but I was wondering if there is good solution to solve this issue..

Comment: Well apparently there is:) I was also unaware of that:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <vector>
#include <set>

template <typename T, template <typename...> class Base = std::vector>
class A : public Base<T>
{
};

int main()
{
    A<int> a;
    A<int, std::set> b;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8f4b38565a438ff3)

Comment: Apparently my comment about this being impossible due to that fact that the compilation will fail due to missing template arguments was totally of and I was wrong, I was not aware of this:) Does this work in C++14 only? MSVC 2012 is refusing to compile this.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis it utilizes only C++11 features, MSVC 2012 is not fully C++11-compliant

Comment: @PiotrS. thanks:) I know that MSVC 2012 was is not fully compliant, that is why I asked - wanted to know if this was a missing feature or C++14. Thanks again, learned something new:) Can you very briefly explain why the compiler does not complain about missing template argumnets for `std::set` ?

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis this is known as a *template template parameter*

Comment: @PiotrS. Thanks for giving a name to that, I will try to find some more doc about this :)

Comment: @PiotrS. Sorry I have another question: is it possible in this case to have a method "add" that uses push_back() when Base is a vector and insert() when Base is a set?